# Next.js 13.4 API streaming: tokens streamed individually on localhost, but on production they arrive all at once

Tags: node.js, next.js, streaming

I have encountered an issue with API streaming in Next.js 13.4 (using the app router) where tokens are being sent all at once on the production environment, instead of one at a time as expected. Surprisingly, the code works fine on my localhost setup. I am running the same Node version (v18.16.1) on both my localhost and the production environment (Digital Ocean droplet).

To provide some context, I have created a minimal functional example that demonstrates the issue:

```
// FILE: app\api\chat\route.js
export async function POST(request) {
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            for (const word of ['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test.']) {
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)); // To emulate a delay
                const queue = encoder.encode(JSON.stringify({chunk: word}));
                controller.enqueue(queue);
            }
            controller.close();
        },
    });
    return new NextResponse(stream);
}
```

And on the client-side:

```
const response = await fetch(`/api/chat`, { method: 'POST' });
const reader = response.body.getReader();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
while (true) {
    const {value, done} = await reader.read();
    if (done) break;
    console.log(decoder.decode(value));
}
```

On my localhost, each token is printed with a one-second delay between them. However, when I upload the code to the production environment, I receive all four console.log() messages simultaneously, after a four-second delay.

I have already attempted to use TransformStream instead of ReadableStream, but the same issue occurs (works locally, but not remotely).

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding why this discrepancy is occurring between the localhost and production environments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the issue. The host is using Nginx, and all I had to to was to disable buffering on Nginx config:

```
proxy_buffering off
```